# How to insert COUNT value of another table in column of a table

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey I have a two tables

**Likes**

[image: Likes]

And other table

**Comments**

[image: Likes]

I want to total likes  in comment table . How can i achieve this . I just write fake query in comments table just for understanding i want effect like that , any ideas please

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO Destination(Col)
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Source;
```

Comment: I just want automatically insert that values in tables , i don't want to write query for every field

Comment: TEJA can u please explain it

Comment: If you want to insert the count of one table into another then specify the source/destination tables. This is for all rows in the table...

Comment: If you want it "automatically" you could have your application run the query every time a comment is made to update the counts or update then at the time they are needed (shown to the user).

Answer (score 1):

You can use triggers to automatically update `comments` tables based on `likes` table.

The following in an **Insert After Trigger** which will increment the value of `total_likes` of the corresponding `comment_id by` one in `comments` table when an insert in performed in `likes` table.

You have to give initial value of `total_likes` for comments as zero when inserting in `comments` table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_likes AFTER INSERT ON likes 
FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE comments
     SET total_likes = total_likes+1
   WHERE comment_id = NEW.comment_id;
```

Comment: bhai main chataa hun ki jab koi banda comment ko like krai to mujai sirf comments table ko modidy karna padai. dusri table apnai aap update ho zayai. terai method sai to mujai ek or query likhni pdagai

Comment: @user7025447 When an Entry in likes tables happens, the trigger automatically fires and the comments tables is updated. You dont need to write any extra query.Just insert into likes table

Comment: where should i write this trigger @jophab

Comment: Run it in your phpmyqdmin

Comment: @user7025447 Is it solved by this method? If yes feel free to mark as correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a query that resolve this.
I suggest some like this:

```
select comment_id,uploader,
(select count(*) from likes l where L.COMMENT_ID =CM.COMMENT_ID ) nlikes
from commments cm;
```